# Get image object on load with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, onload, jquery-events

I load an image like this:

```
$('img').bind('load', function (event) {
    var image = event.target;
    var $image = $(image);
    ...
 });
```

What I want is to be able to get the same variables, but without having a load event. So what is actually stored on image and on `$image`, and is there a way to get the same data but without an event?

Comment: In what context? What result do you want to get exactly?

Comment: Couldn't you just store the url of an image in a variable, or better still, just call an image when it is needed with its url using jQuery or php etc? Please explain why you dont want the 'load' and it'd be easier to construct an answer :)

Comment: I am using this plugin http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/color-thief/ so I want to actually send my image there so the canvas can uses it.

Comment: can you write an attempt to get the output you wish?